# foundation.min.js giving issue while using for slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are the files I'm using for the slider revolution but getting some error message :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined foundation.min.js:18
v.extend.each foundation.min.js:18
a.fn.cssAnimationRemove jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js:18
(anonymous function)

```js
<!-- Included JS Files (Compressed) -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.foundation.js"></script> 

<!-- Slider Revolution JS FILES  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/slider-revolution/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/slider-revolution/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>

<!-- Tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>

<!-- CarouFredSel plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.3-packed.js"></script>
<!-- optionally include helper plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>

<!-- Titan Lightbox -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/titan/js/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/titan/js/jquery.titanlighbox.js"></script>


This is the html code which is giving issue as of I think(or you can say I found):
```

```html
<li data-transition="slotfade-horizontal" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="300" data-thumb="images/sliders/sliderrevolution/thumbs/thumb1.jpg" ><img src="images/sliders/sliderrevolution/slides/vodafone_slide01.jpg"  alt="">
  <div class="caption lfl big_color"  data-x="595" data-y="130" data-speed="300" data-start="1200" data-easing="easeOutExpo">WELCOME TO YOUR </div>
  <div class="caption lfl big_color"  data-x="595" data-y="167" data-speed="300" data-start="1200" data-easing="easeOutExpo">LEARNING JOURNEY</div>                            
  <div class="caption lfb"  data-x="600" data-y="285" data-speed="300" data-start="1500" data-easing="easeOutExpo"><a class="button" data-reveal-id="Login">Login</a></div>
</li>
```

Comment: You'll need to show your code also, not just the scripts. Somewhere in that code it looks like your calling `.length` on something thats undefined.

Comment: e.length is there in foundation.min.js file, which we are using.
and i dont think there will be any issue in that file.